# Microsoft-graph API email messages detecting deleted email

Tags: python, outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the delta query api as specified in the docs

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/{id}/messages/delta?%24deltaToken={token}`

I'm trying to detect deleted messages in the outlook folder. 
I managed to detect if  they are in the 'Trash Folder'. The problem is, this isn't able to detect if the user has message in a folder, delete from the 'trash', then delete permanently.

E.g. of flow

1. Message in inbox
2. Delete message from inbox
3. Delete message from 'Trash' folder

I have a delta query token monitoring for the 'Trash' Folder but whenever the sync runs, it doesn't detect any activity in the Trash folder.
However,  if the user stopped at step 2 and my sync runs, then step 3 then my sync runs. I am able to detect that the message is permanently deleted.

How do I detect if the message was deleted when the user does step 2 and step 3 consecutively then my sync runs?